# Can I apply for a work permit if I am already in Russia as a tourist?

Tags: russia

Can I apply for a work permit or visa when I'm already in Russia with a 10-day tourist visa?

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that you could accomplish that, as it takes longer than 10 days for a work permit to be issued after registration at the [General Directorate of Migratory Affairs](https://xn--b1ab2a0a.xn--b1aew.xn--p1ai/) of the Ministry of Interior of the Russian Federation (GUVM, its acronym in Russian).

In addition, the employer requires permission to hire a foreign citizen. The best way to get a work permit is through the employer.  [Expatica](http://www.expatica.com/ru/visas-and-permits) has a useful guide on what is needed to move to Russia and [how to get a work permit](http://www.expatica.com/ru/visas-and-permits/How-to-get-a-work-permit-in-Moscow_104101.html).

Answer (score 0):

No. When a visitor applies for tourist visa, they declare tourist intention.

It is possible to get a work permit in 10 days, but when you apply for the permit, you should provide your passport. And if authorities would see a tourist visa you will be deported.

For work purposes there are special work visas. Any potential applicant should apply for them.

Comment: Do you have some links to back this up? - especially since parts of your question conflict with what was said in an earlier answer.

Comment: @JanDoggen 

Russian laws

1. ФЗ-114 "О порядке въезда из Российской Федерации и выезда в Российскую Федерацию"

2. 115-ФЗ "О правовом положении иностранных граждан в Российской Федерации"